# How much should I pay to bank for educational loan?

Tags: india, banking, student-loan, interest

I have a bank loan taken from one of the nationalised bank and I owe 4.54 lakhs at 11% interest to the respected bank

I have not paid since last 2 years towards interest

So I wanted to know how much should I pay now every month?Please help me

Comment: Give your bank a call first. They will be able to help and inform you what to do and how much to pay.

Comment: If you give us the original length of the loan (ie, 30 year, 20 year, etc), we could do an amortization table, but keep in mind that your bank may charge fees and penalties for missing 24 payments, so talking to your bank is best.

Answer (score 2):

You need to talk to your Bank and understand the total amount due and the interest accrued and how you can start making the payments the amount and duration.